# Put tags at the top if they have been edited?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

For a lot of edits the only thing that has change is the set of tags for that question. Very rarely do they write what tags they have changed, and even if they did I feel like I would have to scroll to the bottom of the question to verify that.

It would be extremely convenient if the new set of tags then would have been put at the top. Based on the question title I would often be able to reject / improve edit without the extra scroll each time.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve [perfection](http://www.near-perfection.com/)?

Comment: I'm always trying to achieve perfection. :)

Comment: Perhaps it might make sense to always put them at the top, even if they weren't changed ?

Comment: Hope this [user script](http://stackapps.com/q/6771/37357) will help you.

Comment: Without looking at the rest of the question how do you know they have done ALL the edits they should have.