# Edit review should show more clearly if it's a question or an answer

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

This feature request is in response to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327052/why-is-this-a-bad-edit-review-worthy-of-a-review-suspension). A question that is also marked as [a duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261812/you-approved-edits-on-something-that-clearly-wasnt-an-answer).

When reviewing, we need to see if something is a question or an answer. This is information about the context of the post, that affects how it should be reviewed.

If someone posts a question as an answer, it counts as Low Quality and should be flagged as such.
However, if it is edited, the flags are reset. So any edit suggestions on these should be rejected.

So, edit reviewers *need* to see if a post is a question or an answer.

This information is available, but in small letters at the bottom of the suggestion.
I propose that this information is put at the top, and in **boldface**.
Then the context of the review is immediately clear to the reviewer.

Comment: Having the tags at the bottom of the answer like that, just as they would be when viewing a question, is particularly confusing. That problem hasn't caught my eye before; have they always been there?

Comment: @JoshCaswell As far as I can remember, yes. But are you referring to the "asked"/"answerd", or to the tags? There is also a feature-request to put tags at the top when reviewing, somewhere.

Comment: The tag tags. [These things](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qipIh.png).

Comment: @JoshCaswell Ok. Meanwhile I've found that feature-request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323897/put-tags-at-the-top-if-they-have-been-edited .

Comment: Oh, Meta... The [dupe master](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261812/) of the [question that spawned this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327052/) had [already spawned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261812/you-approved-edits-on-something-that-clearly-wasnt-an-answer#comment63329_261812) this [same request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265992/). Since there's already an answer here, I've voted to dupe close the older request.

Comment: Nevertheless, I still anticipate finding brand new questions that were actually submitted as answers, and still shaking my head in despair.

Comment: @gravity There's another feature-request to address that: [Add placeholder to answer box](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327172/812149).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I was going to request this, so I'm posting what I have as an answer here. I put a lot of effort into putting it all together, and I think it illustrates why this is such a problem.

The thing about the suggested edits queue is that, unlike all the other "mixed" queues, it is very unclear what the post is exactly.

---

### Here are some pictures of the first posts queue:

> [image: This is a first Answer]

> [image: This is a first Question]

I haven't labeled them, but it should be obvious enough what they are.

---

### Here are some pictures from the suggested edits queue:

Can somebody explain why this answer has tags? Or is it an accepted question? (It's really hard to tell if it's a question or an answer when it's not accepted.)

> [image: This is an accepted answer suggested edit.]

And here is a post without a bold title. Can somebody explain to me why the supposed "asker" does not appear to own the post? Their name is white, not blue:

> [image: This is a question suggested edit]

I stole this picture from another question, but it shows that tag edits are also a little confusing. Why is there a vote count? It makes it look like a question/answer:

> [image: This is a tag edit]

The other thing I'm realizing is that editing an edit also has poor UI. While there are a few indications (the ability to edit title & tags), it would be helpful to have the word "question" (or "answer" or "tag wiki") as a bold heading. And we also should get a link back to the original post, since I see nothing currently:

> [image: editing a question in the queue]

---

Essentially, I think we should:

- Add a bold header (like FP) indicating what you're reviewing (Question, answer, tag wiki)
- For questions, highlight the ownership with blue
- For answers, include the question below it. It could either be like FP/LQP or it could be more like a one-box.

  - It might work to include the tags under the question
- When editing in the queue, specify type of post is being edited. In case I forgot or something.
- Add a link to the post when you are editing in the queue. OK, not entirely relevant, but I thought I might as well mention it while I'm redesigning the UI.

Comment: Sorry for beating you to asking the question... but +1 for the answer! I'd also like a link when editing. Let me know if you post a feature request for that!

Comment: The link to the post is in the post title (whatever post type it is: Q, A, wiki, etc).

Comment: @NathanTuggy No, there is no such link (see my new picture). In fact, it does not explicitly state what you are editing either...

Comment: @Laurel: Oh, you mean after you've started editing.

Comment: Totally sums up ammount of confusion I suffered when reviewing.