# Add placeholder to answer box?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, editor

Stack Overflow already uses placeholders in the comment field. Would it be an idea to *also* have this in the *answer* box itself? This could potentially reduce the work load in the review queues.

Are there any good reasons for having placeholders in the comment section, yet at the same time not having them in the answer section?

[image: Example for an answer box with placeholder text]

Comment: Maybe worth noting that new users already see a pretty big popup with guidance ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2e9B5.png)) which pops up automatically, so I'm not sure they'd read _even more_ information.

Comment: I feel popups are more easily dismissed. Also, the placeholder can be changed later and everybody will still see it.

Comment: "Having placeholders is useful" [I'm not sure that data supports that conclusion](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-placeholders/).

Comment: The biggest problem with placeholders has nothing to do with cognitive impairments and everything to do with the fact that *they go away*, right at the point when they are most useful. If I start writing an answer, and then want to look back at the guidelines or help (which, let's be realistic, no one will read *first*—they clicked on the answer button with a mission), I can't do it without first deleting everything I wrote. Think that's going to happen? Not a chance.

Comment: @zzzzBov Looking closely, the article you linked, titled "Placeholders in Form Fields Are Harmful", does not apply to this use of a placeholder. It's about placeholders where the user actually needs it's content to fill out the field.

Comment: Why were all the comments deleted from here? While it may not be have been OPs intention to have a discussion about whether placeholders are valid, it is a relevant topic to the questions posed.

Comment: @DavidG: The comments that were deleted had less to do with whether placeholders are valid and more to do with name-calling, political correctness, "-ism"s, and similar issues that piss people off.

Comment: @CodyGray, CTRL+X, CTRL+V. I feel this is an excellent idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that is a good idea. We can include something like this:

> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question
>   asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable
>   alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also
>   include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in
>   the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations,
>   assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable,
>   but fuller explanations are better.

Or maybe something like this:

> We don't expect every answer to be perfect, but answers with correct
>   spelling, punctuation and grammar are easier to read. They also tend
>   to get upvoted more frequently. Remember, you can always go back at
>   any time and edit your answer to improve it.

I guess anything from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer would be helpful.

**Update**

For those who think that the proposed texts (quoted from [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page) are way too long, I want to add some clarification.

- I don't suggest to add those texts directly into `placeholder` attribute of `<textarea>` tag that is used for the answer.
- Those are just texts that I suggest to use as source for the placeholder.
- Choose any sentence from those or any other sentence from linked page, the most of them will do good.

As one of the sentences says:

> Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is
>   helpful...

I hope my answer is not an exception ;)

Comment: *Waaay* too long. What are the chances that someone is going to read all that text in the first box? And worse, that they're going to read it *before* they type the first letter, making it insta-disappear? Practically 0. Also, too preachy. The very first sentence is like wagging your finger at a potential answerer. We don't want to discourage people from answering the question, we just want to guide them into doing it in a useful fashion. Telling someone as the very first instruction to "Read the question carefully" is just insulting.

Comment: I agree a placeholder needs to be short. It needs to be short enough to be mostly read during the time between recognizing where to write the answer, and starting to actually type.

Comment: I think the OP's example text is a great starting point. This is pretty long.

Comment: Clarification, I suggested source that can be used to extract placeholder  and provided my favorite parts of it, but **not** placeholder text extracted already. All of them are from http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and sure length matters and it should not be long.

Answer (score 31):

Post your answer here. Include enough information to make the answer self-contained. Answers are not for asking new questions, commenting or saying thanks (cast a vote instead).

Comment: Normally, a placeholder will disappear once you start typing something ...

Comment: Indeed, otherwise we would have seen a lot of comments reading "Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”.". :)

Comment: @Glorfindel: Yeah, ["normally."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94917/dont-allow-placeholder-question-title-text-to-be-submitted-as-question-title)

Comment: @Christian Jonassen: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JY2Bd.png

Comment: Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”.

Comment: If placeholders can be used anywhere, they can be used anywhere. No reason that it should be used to assist users writing comments but not users writing answers.

Comment: Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks", and don't attempt to answer the question in comments.

Comment: So your argument against this feature is that there are trolls and idiots on SO? Or am I missing the point here?

Comment: @Stijn: Just doing what I do best on meta.

Comment: How long has the comments box had a placeholder? I had to check following OP's comment here as I don't think I've ever noticed it before.

Comment: Funny answer, but terrible answer if you're using this to say it shouldn't be done. If a placeholder doesn't disappear upon focus or at least first key, then it's a horribly designed or coded placeholder.

Comment: Guys, quit reading so much into it. Come on.

Answer (score -2):

Answer here! See our [hints](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)  for writing good answers.

Comment: I didn't know placeholders could contain clickable links now.

Comment: Through the magic of jQuery, all things are possible.

Comment: Oh, I admit I did not even think about that - it may indeed not be possible. How to find out? I think a link would help a lot to make the placeholder short and still convey detail information directly enough. Most important is avoiding to require the users impulse to actively search for the help texts. It may be easy to find, but that is unrelated.

Comment: @CodyGray That's certainly a true fact. Not sure - are you saying/implying to have an actual approach or reference above that? Of course, stating the mere fact was extremely useful already!

Answer (score -2):

## Short

A placeholder needs to be short. It needs to be short enough to be mostly read during the time between recognizing where to write the answer, and starting to actually type. Thai is roughly the time between seeing it and finishing to navigate to it, plus the delay in interaction until the user types a character, which varies depending on a lot of factors.

I did not check the literature, but I'm sure it is very important to make the placeholder short to make it work. Making it work means getting the main point of the information to the users attention before the text vanishes.

### Keep detail information close-by

To make a text short, but have the details still closely at hand, using a link to the detail information would help.

I am not sure whether it is technically possible to use a link as part of the placeholder text; Let me know if you have knowledge about this, (or just edit this paragraph).

### Choosing a short text

Assuming a link can be used, the text should be so short that it can understood at a glance. All he needs to get initially is that we offer advice very closely.

I suspect that a long text directly including some details creates a big risk to make the user feel he does not want to read it before starting to write.

Some ideas for short placeholder texts with a link:

a:

> Answer here! See our [hints](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)  for writing good answers.

b:

> Type your answer here. We have [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to make it good!

c:

> Your answer goes here. [Learn](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) how to write good answers!

Comment: A placeholder is an attribute value, and thus cannot contain unescaped HTML.

Comment: @CodyGray The comment of MikeMcCaughan may be relevant regarding using `jquery` to solve it?

Comment: I believe @Cody's remark was a joke. Using jQuery to fix everything is a common meme on meta.

Comment: Ok... but, as an optimist, I note that this does not imply it's not - confined to this use case - actually true! Let's see...

Comment: @VolkerSiegel The jQuery comment was [referencing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/212576) this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif