# When is the "Your Answer" popup above the answer box shown?

Tags: support, answers, new-users, not-an-answer, user-experience

I was thinking about alternatives to the [feature request proposed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370586/your-answer-to-the-question-at-the-top-of-this-page) and started thinking about a placeholder text-based solution ([once proposed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327172/add-placeholder-to-answer-box)).

While tooling around while logged out from the site, I discovered that we already have a potential solution to the problem those proposals are trying to fix. (That is, new users not being informed enough about what the answer box is for.)

It's in the form of a popup that appears when the input box gains focus:

[image: Your Answer popup]

That seems pretty clear to me, but we still routinely have NAA answers posted which ask for help or merely comment on another post.

What are the conditions under which this popup is shown? Is it only shown while logged out, or is it also shown to e.g. logged in users with new accounts? I don't see it while logged in to my usual account.

Comment: The first question is who sees it, the second question is whether the people who see it actually read it or decide to not post an inappropriate answer as a result.